# How to secure a folder in an ASP.NET application based on the user's session?

Tags: asp.net, session

I have an application where resources specific to the user are stored in a folder based on their session id. For example : `[root folder]/resources/[user session id]/`

I need to prevent other users from being able to access another user's resources. I'm thinking the best place to set this up is in the Global.asax file and analyze the current request and validate against the user's session. Is there a 'best practice' for this kind of thing? Any other ideas?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are storing _session_ based data (which is volatile/good only for the session) that way - vs. say, _user_ based data (which can be persistent or not) --- you did say "specific to user"(?).

Comment: @EdSF The resources folder is temporary storage for the current user only. There will multiple active resources for all users logged into the system at the same time, once the user logs out(session ends) their resources are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can check always before allowing access to resources that current user session id = user session id.

Best regards.